# AngularJS routing configuration error

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am currently learning AngularJS and I got stuck with Angular Routing section.
I cannot route from one view to another; can someone help me and point where have my code is wrong?

Here there are my [home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcLoZ.png), [index.html and demo.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF1KM.png).

Comment: it should be Myapp.controller and .otherwise should redirect to a url not a template and post ur code here instead of the image

Comment: what error are you getting ?